# Why Git clone from Gerrit(port 29418) is much slower than Git(port 22)

Tags: gerrit, git-clone

As the title describe.

I made many test on this.

And how can I speed up Gerrit Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once cloned, check what is is fetching with:

```
 time b git fetch --all -v
```

If you see *many* `origin/branches`, you might to [cleanup old Gerrit branches](https://gist.github.com/nikreiman/5458386) in order to not clone/fetch so many branches.

Check also if "Git port 22" refers to the same Gerrit server, or to another Git hosting service: in the latter case, any comparison would be unfair.

Comment: @nervermore It will, once you have prunes the gerrit branches which are no longer needed: the clone will then be faster.