# Git clone from Gerrit is hanging on 'Cloning into'

Tags: gerrit, git-clone

I got a **ssh** clone url from Gerrit website.

```
git clone "ssh://username@server:29418/code-repo"
```

But it's really slow and hang on for quite a while on 'Cloning into xxx'.

```
Thu Jul 22 09:53:47 CST 2021
Cloning into 'code'...
remote: Total 14828 (delta 0), reused 14828 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (14828/14828), 5.68 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (6532/6532), done.
Thu Jul 22 09:54:04 CST 2021
```

While on another Gerrit ，**same** repo is downloaded in **one** second.

```
Thu Jul 22 09:34:43 CST 2021
Cloning into 'code'...
remote: Counting objects: 14828, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (14828/14828)
remote: Total 14828 (delta 6521), reused 14806 (delta 6521)
Receiving objects: 100% (14828/14828), 5.69 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (6521/6521), done.
Thu Jul 22 09:34:44 CST 2021
```

Why Gerrit is hanging on cloning into ... ?

How can I fix it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Addition log shows that Gerrit get user's request as soon as CLONE starts.So its not caused by poor Network .

Comment: Did you check if the first Gerrit repo had many branches, as I recommended in your pre;vious question https://stackoverflow.com/a/68465644/6309?

Comment: Yes, i did. Vonc. Both this two repo have 500+ branches. I Will reply you after a prune work.

Comment: Branch count is the same for both repo.But download speed is so different,that's odd.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed by running GC.
I do not know why.